# How do I create a customer on stripe without enter card information

Tags: php, stripe-payments

there I would like to create a customer on stripe without the user entering their card information to begin with. When a user signs-up to my website, i would like them to also have an account created with stripe. I want information such as address to be stored on stripe from signing up on my website. So when the user does want to purchase an item the information can then be retrieved from stripe. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe is for processing payments. It isn't a customer management platform.

If you want to store user information like addresses prior to taking payments through Stripe, you'll need to store them yourself.